# Parsing text in php

Tags: php, parsing

I have a string of the following format:

**xxx xxx xxx xxx**

Now each part can be any of these values: abc, "abc", (abc), NIL

where abc is a string which may also have spaces, parentheses, quotes.

**Example string:**

TEXT "PLAIN" ("NAME" "file(1).txt") NIL

What is the best way to parse such a string into an array? i.e.

array[0] = TEXT

array[1] = "PLAIN"

array[2] = ("NAME" "file(1).txt")

array[3] = NIL

Comment: Wouldn't `explode`ing this string by a space work? `$arr=explode(' ', $str);`

Comment: why don't you have your string in XML format?

Comment: No. It's a response from a server via fsockopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regular expression will help you:

```
    $result=array();
    $subject = 'TEXT "PLAIN" (string with spaces) "string with other spaces" ("NAME" "file(1).txt") NIL';
    $regex = '
    /"([^"])+"                   # Match quote, followed by multiple non-quotes, ended by a quote.
    |(\([\w ]+\))                # Or match multiple words and spaces between parentheses
    |\(((?=")([^)]|(?>"|.))+)\)  # Or Match text between parentheses, ignore ending parenthese if inside a quote
    |\w+                         # Or match single words
    /x';

    preg_match_all($regex, $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    $result = $result[0];
    print_r($result);

    print_r($result);
```

Test String :

```
 TEXT "PLAIN" (string with spaces) "string with other spaces" ("NAME" "file(1).txt") NIL
```

Result :

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => TEXT
        [1] => "PLAIN"
        [2] => (string with spaces)
        [3] => "string with other spaces"
        [4] => ("NAME" "file(1).txt")
        [5] => NIL
    )
```

Comment: As an application maintainer, I must say I _love_ regexp... You won't remeber what it does in two hours + you won't be easily able to modify it if the format changes a little...

Comment: Well. This works too. Even with spaces within quotes. But I think I need to read about regex. I have never worked with it before. Thanks @tpaksu.

Comment: @adrien Although the regular expression itself is awesome, I too have problems with maintaining them. Something not a lot of people know is that it is possible to document regexes inline, if you pass the 'x' modifier. This has helped me enormously in the past. I've updated the code to reflect this, but tpaksu can roll it back if he doesn't like it ;)

Comment: No, it's better this way. Thanks @BerryLangerak.

Comment: Its much better to understand it now. Thanks @BerryLangerak.

Comment: @tpaksu, I found a small bug in the code. I am still trying to get a hang of regexp, but can you tell me how can I fix this.
If I change the input string (just replacing quotes with brackets) to this: TEXT "PLAIN" (string with spaces) ("NAME" "file(1).txt") NIL
The output gives the two parts in parentheses as one. One way would be to check the result by each character and split it.

Comment: That's not a small bug, that's what you wanted before.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$input = 'TEXT "PLAIN" ("NAME" "file(1).txt") NIL';
$output = array();

$open = 0;
$parts = explode(' ', $input);
for ($i = $j = 0; $i < count($parts); $i++) {
    $open += substr_count($parts[$i], '(');
    $open -= substr_count($parts[$i], ')');

    $output[$j] .= $parts[$i];

    if ($open == 0) {
        $j++;
    }
}

var_dump($output);
```

What I do is simple : exploding the string in parts by cutting on spaces, then determining if we are inside parathesis or not to re-assemble parts when needed.

Comment: Thats a good idea. It works. I ll modify the code to identify spaces within quotes too. Thanks